# react navigation, go back with nested navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

```
Stack Navigator :
 - Login
 - Register
 - Activation
 - Tab Navigator
    + Home
    + Histories
    + Cart
    + Profile
 - Outlet
 - Product
```

I have problem with go back navigation, when I'm in Product Screen I can go to "Cart Screen" using `navigation.navigate('Cart');`, but while in "Cart Screen" and `goBack()` my screen go to "Home Screen".
How to manage `goBack()` from stack screen to tab screen?

Comment: Send that section's ```navigation``` using props ( custom navigator) or use context-api or redux, then trigger it after ```popToTop``` for performance reasons and avoid memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

In react-navigation (before 5), I did achieved to that you say with passing upper navigation as a prop to downward using custom navigation component like this:

```js
// this component's navigation is replaced by upper navigation, you can send another prop if you need both navigations.
const MyComponent0 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Child1: {
      screen: Child1,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
        return {
          headerRight: (
            // you can use BackButton of library with import it, I wrote my own, that time i didn't know there is a ready importable back button.
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{paddingLeft: 10}}
              onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
              <Icon ios="ios-menu" android="md-menu" style={{color: '#fff'}} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerTitle: <Text style={styles.whiteText}>Child1 title</Text>,
          headerLeft: (
            <HeaderBackButton
              style={{color: '#FFF'}}
              onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)}
            />
          ),
        };
      },
    },
    Child2,
    ...
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 13,
        ...Platform.select({
          android: {
            fontFamily: ...,
          },
          ios: {
            fontFamily: ...,
          },
        }),
      },
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
      },
      headerTintColor: 'white',
    },
  },
);


class MyComponent1 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  static router = MyComponent0.router;

  render() {
    return <MyComponent0 navigation={this.props.navigation} />; // you can send like navigation1 if you need downward navigation too.
  }
}
```

This code is in old approach, but it works using react-navigation before 5.
I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method

```
    const goNext = () => {
                navigation.navigate('componentWithDrawer', {
                    screen: next_screen,
                    params: { previous_screen: current_srceen }
                }, next_screen)
                navigation.toggleDrawer()
            }
}
```

then for go back

```
const goBack = () => {
                navigation.navigate('componentWithDrawer', {
                    screen: useRoute().params.previous_screen,
                }, next_screen)
                navigation.toggleDrawer()
            }
}
```